# Looping over changing date gap for R

Tags: r, loops, date, datetime

trying to create a loop of large data processing, but I need to create a loop that can automatically input the next game date in the data sequence (descending order), I have currently been doing by hand and just inputting the game date, and previous game date but need to create a loop that will change the date after each run through. Any suggestions?

Example Dates from "game_date"

[image]

Select game

```
 Raw_Data2$game_date <- strptime(Raw_Data2$game_date, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
 format(Raw_Data2$game_date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
 Player1 = Raw_Data2[Raw_Data2$game_date == **"2018-06-10"**, ]
```

Create rest factor

```
 date1 <- strptime(**"04.06.2018"**, format="%d.%m.%Y")

 date2 <- strptime(**"10.06.2018"**, format="%d.%m.%Y")

 Days.Rest <- as.numeric(date2 - date1)  

  Rest.factor <- if(is.na(Days.Rest)){
   Rest.factor <- 1
   } else if(Days.Rest>= 4){
   Rest.factor <- 1
  } else if(Days.Rest== 1){
   Rest.factor <- 5
  } else if(Days.Rest>= 2){
   Rest.factor <- 2
  }
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  Instead of `if/else` use `ifelse`. It is nto clear from the code, where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` to get date from the previous row and subtract it with current row to get `days.rest` using which you can calculate `Rest.factor`.

```
library(dplyr)

Result <- Raw_Data2 %>%
            mutate(game_date = as.Date(game_date), 
                   days.rest = as.numeric(game_date - lag(game_date)), 
                   Rest.factor = case_when(is.na(days.rest) | days.rest >= 4 ~ 1L,
                                           days.rest == 1 ~ 5L, 
                                           days.rest >= 2 ~ 2L))
```

Comment: Thank you for the info on using lag this will be super helpful.. however, is there a way to automatically select the next game_date from a data frame? I.e. if I want to loop the code to run for Day1 - Day2.. then loop (repeat) to calculate Day2 - Day3..?

Comment: @LoganMcCallcI think this is what `lag` does. You can subtract current value by previous value which is stored in `days.rest`. If this doesn't work as intended for you please create a small reproducible example and show expected output for the same. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269